# SQL query seconds to date (Ssms12)

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms, ssms-2012

on the stackoverflow site in fount Thad `select CONVERT(CHAR(10), DATEADD(second, MAX(60), 0), 108)` will result in 00:01:00  (that's true btw :-) )

now I want to integrate this in the following query (for Ssms12):

```
SELECT Run.TaskName,history.runtime
,CONVERT(CHAR(10), DATEADD(second, MAX(history.runtime), 0), 108)

FROM dbo.history
INNER JOIN Run
ON dbo.history.TaskID=Run.TaskID
```

whatever I try, I can't get this to work in the above example, does anyone have an idea how to fix this?

**error:** Column 'Run.TaskName' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to group by other columns where you are not using aggregate function:

```
SELECT Run.TaskName,history.runtime,
   CONVERT(CHAR(10), DATEADD(second, history.runtime, 0), 108)
FROM dbo.history
INNER JOIN Run ON dbo.history.TaskID=Run.TaskID
```

You are using MAX for runtime so you can do like :

```
SELECT Run.TaskName,MAX(history.runtime) runtime,
    CONVERT(CHAR(10), DATEADD(second, MAX(history.runtime), 0), 108)
FROM dbo.history
INNER JOIN Run ON dbo.history.TaskID=Run.TaskID
GROUP BY Run.TaskName
```

It means either you have to remove MAX from runtime or you have to use group by for rest of columns.

Comment: tx :-) **MAX** is the problem becouse i dont want to group

Answer (score 1):

Most probably you needn't MAX. `select CONVERT(CHAR(10), DATEADD(second, 60, 0), 108)` is OK, so

```
SELECT Run.TaskName,history.runtime
      ,CONVERT(CHAR(10), DATEADD(second, history.runtime, 0), 108)
FROM dbo.history 
INNER JOIN dbo.Run
    ON dbo.history.TaskID=dbo.Run.TaskID
```

Comment: i wish i had found Thad myselfe, tx for the grate help

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have necessary permissions to Run table and use the full qualified table as below if the table exists and you have necessary permission to read the tables

```
SELECT Run.TaskName,history.runtime
      ,CONVERT(CHAR(10), DATEADD(second, MAX(history.runtime), 0), 108)
FROM dbo.history 
INNER JOIN dbo.Run
    ON dbo.history.TaskID=dbo.Run.TaskID
```